# Bootstrap: how to move form fields to their own lines in mobile view?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a gorgeous Bootstrap form that works great and is beautifully responsive for mobile. However, some form fields get too narrow when they're on a mobile screen.

For example, here's a few fields from the desktop version, which is awesome:

[image: desktop version of form]

And here's the same part of that form, but in the mobile view:

[image]

As you can see, the fields get a little narrow. I'd much prefer the form to just wrap these fields onto their own lines at 100% width. Is there a way to do that in Bootstrap?

Comment: Maybe provide the markup so we can assist you better?

Answer (score 0):

for mobile secreen use class col-xs-12 and for desktop use col-lg-12
for more info visit this site
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Why col-lg-12 instead of col-lg-4?

Comment: this will decrease the size to 4 columns instead 12.basically whole secreen is devided into 12 columns so if you use col-lg -4 it will utilize just 4 columns out of 12 so if you want to display it like large secreen u have to use col-lg-12.

Comment: you also should have to visit that link that i have given u before thats too much informative

Comment: download bootstrap files into you css folder then use these classes

Comment: For 3 equal columns across a single row, they would use `col-md-4` or `col-lg-4`, not `col-lg-12`. Even states it *Grid columns are created by specifying the number of twelve available columns you wish to span. For example, three equal columns would use three .col-xs-4.* https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

Comment: @ChrisYongchu but for country he should use col-lg-12

Comment: Bootstrap is mobile first. So he can use `col-xs-12` if he wants. But yes he would use `12` for the select list (i.e. Country).

Answer (score 0):

The layout you are looking for is

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7z9a10s2/1/)

Comment: `col-md-12` is redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap framework has various classes to help with this. First of all make sure all of your form fields have the `form-control` class applied. This makes your controls go to 100% width of the container. Secondly use the `col-*` classes to specify the sizes at different resolutions. As this is Bootstrap, always think mobile first. For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input id="country" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <input id="city" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <input id="state" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <input id="zipcode" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```